# Flash CS6, AS3 button issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the code below to have button "legalBtn" access the layer and instance name of "legalOverlay." Then after the legalese has been read, the enduser can close the "legalOverlay" via "closeBtn" and return to the last frame of the banner ad.  The code below has no compiler errors, but the "legalBtn" is still not working. Any ideas?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

function init(){
    legalBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, legalClick);
    legalBtn.visible=true;

    legalOverlay.clickthru.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK);
    legalOverlay.clickthru.buttonMode=true;
    legalOverlay.closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK);
    legalOverlay.closeBtn.buttonMode=true;

    legalOverlay.visible=false;
}
    function legalClick(e:MouseEvent){
        if(legalOverlay.visible==true){
        legalOverlay.visible=false;
        } else {
        legalOverlay.visible=true;
        }
}

stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `init()` function to add the click event listener on your `legalBtn` object and make it visible.